# Use a webservice to get a random video and play it. C# WPF

Tags: c#

I need help figuring out where to start on using a webservice to get a random video to play. This is the program instructions I am working on:

For this problem, you will be using a webservice to get a random video to play.  The webservice can be found at : http://pcbstuou.w27.wh-2.com/webservices/3033/api/random/video . You will want to have a button to get a random video from the webservice for the user to press as well as a play and stop button.  When the video is playing, the play button should double as a pause button and should change the text to reflect the available option.

This is what I have:

```
namespace Problem3
{
    public partial class Media
    {
        private bool mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        public mePlayer;

        private void Open_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Media files (*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg)|*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                mePlayer.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }

        private void Play_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = (mePlayer != null) && (mePlayer.Source != null);
        }

        private void Play_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mePlayer.Play();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
        }

        private void Stop_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = mediaPlayerIsPlaying;
        }

        private void Stop_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mePlayer.Stop();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        }
```

The meplayer is having an error and I obviously need to create a method for it, but what would the method include? Also, I  am not sure if I even went about this right?

This is the Main:

```
namespace Problem3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Search_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, object mediaElement)
        {
            //var FullVimeoUrl = "http://pcbstuou.w27.wh-2.com/webservices/3033/api/random/video ";

            //mediaElement.Source = new Uri(FullVimeoUrl.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            //mediaElement.Play();
        }

        private void Search_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var FullVimeoUrl = "http://pcbstuou.w27.wh-2.com/webservices/3033/api/random/video ";

            mediaElement.Source = new Uri(FullVimeoUrl.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }

        public void VideoPath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private class mediaElement
        {
            public static Uri Source { get; internal set; }

            
        }

        //public string Play()
        //{

        //}

        private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //void OnMouseDownPauseMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
            //{

            //    // The Pause method pauses the media if it is currently running.
            //    // The Play method can be used to resume.
            //    mediaElement.Pause();
            //}


        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am sure I have myself all mixed up because I have been working on this entirely too long. I am at the point of way overthinking!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Use a webservice to get a random video and play it. C# WPF

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Audio_and_Video.MediaPlayerVideoControlSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MediaPlayerVideoControlSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MediaElement Source="http://hubblesource.stsci.edu/sources/video/clips/details/images/hst_1.mpg" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Name="mePlayer" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Name="lblStatus" Content="Not playing..." HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click">Play</Button>
                <Button Name="btnPause" Margin="5,0" Click="btnPause_Click">Pause</Button>
                <Button Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click">Stop</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Class File:

```
using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
    
    namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Audio_and_Video
    {
        public partial class MediaPlayerVideoControlSample : Window
        {
            public MediaPlayerVideoControlSample()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                timer.Start();
            }
    
            void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(mePlayer.Source != null)
                {
                    if(mePlayer.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
                        lblStatus.Content = String.Format("{0} / {1}", mePlayer.Position.ToString(@"mm\:ss"), mePlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
                }
                else
                    lblStatus.Content = "No file selected...";
            }
    
            private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mePlayer.Play();
            }
    
            private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mePlayer.Pause();
            }
    
            private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mePlayer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds ridiculous but what do I put in the Stop(), Pause() and Play() methods (in the main window)

Comment: Also, I do not need a separate button for pause, I need the play button to function as a pause button as well.